# Regex, Making A Basic Title

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I am currently using Regex and I have absolutely no idea how to. I got somewhere with the help of msdn, but not far enough:

So below I copied and pasted Regex code that I want to include with another rule I need.
This code below does not allow special characters as well as numbers in the field:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,40}$", ErrorMessage = 
        "Numbers and special characters are not allowed in the Title.")]
```

I need this as well as a restriction on using capital letters after every space.

Example: Every Day I Learn Something New <--Correct
but not: Every day i learn something new. <--Incorrect

Just like making a title for an article.

If you can help out an uneducated Regex coder that would be much appreciated

Cheers

Comment: FYI, some of us have lowercase words as part of our names.. Example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_von_Humboldt - also, movie/book titles will often have lowercased 'of', 'a', etc.

Comment: mmm, thanks for the insight. I wonder if that would be an issue for my client. I guess maybe leaving that tad-bit out would be more beneficial then not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word) describes how to do negative matches. For your case, you could also require that string match `@"^((?!\s[a-z]).)*$"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
([A-Z]+[A-Za-z]*\s+)*
```

You can test your Regex on this site [Regex Tester](http://regexpal.com/)